# How Can I Return a TXT file Using Flask Response?

Tags: python, flask

I have a script ("script2.py") that takes in a particular kind of HTML file, scrapes out some content, and summarizes it in a txt output file. I am building a flask app that will allow a user to upload an HTML file, run the script, and then get a txt output file back in response after they click "submit". These files are really small and I want to avoid saving them anywhere while running the script. **Is there some way to provide a txt file back to the user with the flask response?**

With the code below I can upload a file and get a txt file back in response, but the file only contains these lines...

```
xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?
html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "XHTML1-s.dtd"
```

In the stacktrace, the following error messages are printed.

```
AssertionError: applications must write bytes

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

...

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

The code for my web app is below. The "run_script_in_web_app" function I am calling is the part of the script that converts the HTML file into a txt file.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, Response, make_response
import script2

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def display_home():
    return render_template("home.html")

@app.route('/upload', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def upload_and_run():
    uploaded_file = request.files['file']
    file_name = uploaded_file.filename
    file_contents = uploaded_file.stream.read().decode("utf-8")
    result = script2.run_script_in_web_app(file_name, file_contents)

    response = app.response_class(response=result, status=200, mimetype='application/txt')
    return response

if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run()
```

I realize that this approach is currently insecure because it's not validating user input. I'm just trying to get things running end to end on local host before I layer all that stuff in.

I have run some tests and am pretty confident that the parts of the script "upstream" of the response are working (test HTML file is not empty, upload is working, script2 is able to open the file, etc.)

The function that I am calling is shown below. Comments indicate what is going on in each line.

Here's the function in script2 that I am calling.

```
def run_script_in_web_app(filename, file_contents):

    global soup

    name = filename

# Convert the HTML file contents into a Beautiful Soup object. 

    soup = BeautifulSoup(file_contents)
    return soup

# Creates a dictionary that contains an "author" value extracted from the HTML input file.

    extracted_authors = parse_authors(soup)

# Pulls contents from "header" divs with a certain ID in the input file.

    parse_headers(soup)

# Pulls contents from "body" divs with a certain ID in the input file. 

    parse_bodies(soup)

# Creates a list of dictionaries from header div contents. 

    extracted_heads = extract_headers(header_divs)

# Creates a list of dictionaries from body div contents. 

    extracted_bodies = extract_body(body_divs)

# Combines the header and body dictionaries together into a single list of dictionaries. 

    heads_and_bodies = merge_heads_with_bodies(extracted_heads, extracted_bodies)

# Writes the list of dictionaries and the "author" dictionary together in a .txt file for display to the end user. 

    output_file = dict_writer(extracted_authors, heads_and_bodies, name)
    return (output_file)
```

Comment: The error seems to be in your function ```script2.run_script_in_web_app```. You'll need to show us the contents of that file for us to help in the debug

Comment: @NoCommandLine just updated the post with the function that I'm calling. Thanks for helping out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what was going on here. There were several problems.

1. As @NoCommandLine pointed out, my "run_script_in_web_app" function had two return statements so it was just returning a beautiful soup object rather than the output file that I thought would be returned.
2. The "dict_writer" function I called in "run_script_in_web_app" writes an output file to disk. Instead, I needed to write the outputs into a result, and return that to Flask.

Answer (score 2):

1. I see you are doing `app.response_class` but you don't actually have a custom response class so I wonder why you're doing that. Why not `app.make_response()`
2. But I think your issue is your code - `script2.run_script_in_web_app` is returning a BeautifulSoup object not the actual content of your file. You have to do `soup.body()`

Comment: thanks for the tip. I see that the file I was getting back before contains the head of my HTML input file. I added a line `body = soup.find('body')` and replaced all of the references to "soup" to this "body" in the rest of my function. Now I am getting a blank file in response. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: I'm only using app.response_class because I saw it in a couple code examples. Thanks for the pointer on that.

Comment: don't do ```soup.find('body')```. Do ```soup.body()``` and print the contents and confirm what it contains.